# Delete empty XML nodes using T-SQL FOR XML PATH

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, for-xml-path

I'm using `FOR XML PATH` to construct XML out of a table in SQL Server 2008R2. The XML has to be constructed as follows:

```
<Root>
    <OuterElement>
        <NumberNode>1</NumberNode>
        <FormattedNumberNode>0001</KFormattedNumberNode>
        <InnerContainerElement>
            <InnerNodeOne>0240</InnerNodeOne>
            <InnerNodeStartDate>201201</InnerNodeStartDate>
        </InnerContainerElement>
    </OuterElement>
</Root>
```

According to the schema files, the `InnerContainerElement` is optional, while the `InnerNodeOne` is required. The schema files aren't set up by me, are quite complex, referring each other and not having explicit XSD-namespaces, so I can't easily load them into the database.

The XML has to be created from a table, which is filled using the following query:

```
SELECT
    1 AS NumberNode
    , '0001' AS [FormattedNumberNode]
    , '0240' AS [InnerNodeOne]
    , '201201' AS [InnerNodeStartDate]
INTO #temporaryXMLStore
UNION
SELECT
    2 AS NumberNode
    , '0001' AS [FormattedNumberNode]
    , NULL AS [InnerNodeOne]
    , NULL AS [InnerNodeStartDate]
```

I can think of two ways to construct this XML with `FOR XML PATH`.

1) Using 'InnerContainerElement' as named result from an XML subquery:

```
SELECT
    NumberNode
    , [FormattedNumberNode]
    , (
        SELECT
            [InnerNodeOne]
            , [InnerNodeStartDate]
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ) AS [InnerContainerElement]
FROM #temporaryXMLStore
FOR XML PATH('OuterElement'), ROOT('Root') TYPE
```

2) Using 'InnerContainerElement' as an output element from an XML subquery, but without naming it:

```
SELECT
    NumberNode
    , [FormattedNumberNode]
    , (
        SELECT
            [InnerNodeOne]
            , [InnerNodeStartDate]
        FOR XML PATH('InnerContainerElement'), TYPE
    )
FROM #temporaryXMLStore
FOR XML PATH('OuterElement'), ROOT('Root'), TYPE
```

However, none of them gives the desired result: in both cases, the result looks like

```
<Root>
  <OuterElement>
    <NumberNode>1</NumberNode>
    <FormattedNumberNode>0001</FormattedNumberNode>
    <InnerContainerElement>
      <InnerNodeOne>0240</InnerNodeOne>
      <InnerNodeStartDate>201201</InnerNodeStartDate>
    </InnerContainerElement>
  </OuterElement>
  <OuterElement>
    <NumberNode>2</NumberNode>
    <FormattedNumberNode>0001</FormattedNumberNode>
    <InnerContainerElement></InnerContainerElement>
    <!-- Or, when using the second codeblock: <InnerContainerElement /> -->
  </OuterElement>
</Root>
```

Whenever `InnerContainerElement` is empty, it is still displayed as an empty element. This is invalid according to the schema: whenever the element `InnerContainerElement` is in the XML, `InnerNodeOne` is required too.

How do I construct my `FOR XML PATH` query in such a way that the `InnerContainerElement` is left out whenever it's empty?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make sure that the `InnerContainerElement` has zero rows for the case when there is no content.

```or-sql
select T.NumberNode,
       T.FormattedNumberNode,
       (
         select T.InnerNodeOne,
                T.InnerNodeStartDate
         where T.InnerNodeOne is not null or
               T.InnerNodeStartDate is not null
         for xml path('InnerContainerElement'), type
       )
from #temporaryXMLStore as T
for xml path('OuterElement'), root('Root')
```

Or you could specify the element `InnerContainerElement` as a part of a column alias.

```
select T.NumberNode,
       T.FormattedNumberNode,
       T.InnerNodeOne as 'InnerContainerElement/InnerNodeOne',
       T.InnerNodeStartDate as 'InnerContainerElement/InnerNodeStartDate'
from #temporaryXMLStore as T
for xml path('OuterElement'), root('Root')
```