# Delete empty node in XML file using SQL

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sqlxml

Hi i have created XML file using XML Auto in SQL. The file is created based on the records from six tables. If there is no value in associated table, an empty node is created. Is there a way to delete a empty node in SSIS or SQL?

Below is the query used

```sql
select
(select 

      Opp.OPPORTUNITYID as OPPORTUNITYID,
      Opp.CREATEDATE as RequestDate,
      (select USERNAME from sysdba.USERINFO where USERID=Opp.ACCOUNTMANAGERID) as RepName,
      (select Account from sysdba.ACCOUNT where ACCOUNTID=Opp.ACCOUNTID )as Account,
      (select ACCOUNTID from sysdba.ACCOUNT where ACCOUNTID=Opp.ACCOUNTID ) as AccountID,
      (select MDRPID from sysdba.ACCOUNT where ACCOUNTID=Opp.ACCOUNTID ) as MDRPID,
      (select Coalesce(acc1.accountid,acc.accountid) from sysdba.ACCOUNT  acc  left  join sysdba.ACCOUNT acc1 on acc.UNIVERSITYID = acc1.accountid where acc.ACCOUNTID=Opp.ACCOUNTID ) as UniversityID,
      (select Coalesce(acc1.account,acc.account) from sysdba.ACCOUNT  acc  left  join sysdba.ACCOUNT acc1 on acc.UNIVERSITYID = acc1.accountid where acc.ACCOUNTID=Opp.ACCOUNTID ) as University,
      (Opp.STARTDATE) as StartDate,
      (opp.enddate) as EndDate,
     Coalesce ( opp.PROMOCODE,'') as Promocode,
      Opp.MICROSITEURLKEY as MicrositeURLKey,
      opp.modifydate as ModifyDate,
      (select GUID from sysdba.ACCOUNT where ACCOUNTID=Opp.ACCOUNTID ) as LocationID,
      OppProduct.OPPPRODUCTID as OppProductID,
        OppProduct.PRICE as Price,
      OppProduct.CALCPRICE as CalculatedPrice,
      OppProduct.discount as Discount,
     (select pro.ISBN from sysdba.C_PRODUCT pro join sysdba.OPPORTUNITY_PRODUCT opppro on pro.C_PRODUCTID=opppro.PRODUCTID where opppro.OPPPRODUCTID=OppProduct.OPPPRODUCTID ) as ISBN,
      (select pro.TITLE from sysdba.C_PRODUCT pro join sysdba.OPPORTUNITY_PRODUCT opppro on pro.C_PRODUCTID=opppro.PRODUCTID where opppro.OPPPRODUCTID=OppProduct.OPPPRODUCTID ) as Title,
      AccCourse.ACCOUNTCOURSEID  AS ACCOUNTCOURSEID,
      AccCourse.COURSENAME as CourseName,
      AccCourse.MDRCLGCOURSE as CLGCourse,
      Contact.CONTACTID  as CONTACTID,
      Contact.FIRSTNAME as FirstName,
      Contact.LASTNAME as LastName,
      Contact.EMAIL as Email


from sysdba.OPPORTUNITY Opp
 join sysdba.OPPORTUNITY_PRODUCT OppProduct on Opp.OPPORTUNITYID = OppProduct.OPPORTUNITYID
left join sysdba.C_PRODUCT Product on OppProduct.PRODUCTID = Product.C_PRODUCTID
left join sysdba.OPPPRODUCTCOURSE ProductCourse on OppProduct.OPPPRODUCTID = ProductCourse.OPPPRODUCTID
left join sysdba.OPPORTUNITYCOURSE OppCourse on ProductCourse.OPPORTUNITYCOURSEID = OppCourse.OPPORTUNITYCOURSEID
left join sysdba.ACCOUNTCOURSE AccCourse on OppCourse.ACCOUNTCOURSEID = AccCourse.ACCOUNTCOURSEID
left join sysdba.OPPCOURSECONTACT OppContact on OppCourse.OPPORTUNITYCOURSEID = OppContact.OPPORTUNITYCOURSEID
left join sysdba.CONTACT contact on contact.CONTACTID=OppContact.CONTACTID
For XML AUTO, ROOT('INFO'))as col
```

Output:

```xml
<INFO>
  <Opp LocationID="1594743" ModifyDate="2015-04-01T23:50:01" MicrositeURLKey="O6UJ9A03XT6J" MDRPID="1594743" AccountID="A6UJ9A00OS1L" Account="Marquette University " RepName="Maggie Dolan" RequestDate="2015-04-01T23:48:07" OPPORTUNITYID="O6UJ9A03XT6J">
    <OppProduct Title="prepU for Jensen's Nursing Health Assessment: A Best Practice Approach, Ecommerce, 3 Month Access (PREPU)" ISBN="9781469895727" Price="0.0000" OppProductID="Q6UJ9A15NMSF">
      <AccCourse>
        <contact />
      </AccCourse>
    </OppProduct>
    <OppProduct Title="Lippincott CoursePoint for Nursing Health Assessment: A Best Approach, Ecommerce Version, 12 Month Access (CoursePoint)" ISBN="9781496303134" Price="0.0000" OppProductID="Q6UJ9A15NMSG">
      <AccCourse>
        <contact />
      </AccCourse>
    </OppProduct>
  </Opp>
</INFO>
```

Is there a way to remove the node if its empty? For eg `<Contact>` and `<AccCourse>`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete empty XML nodes using T-SQL FOR XML PATH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468748/delete-empty-xml-nodes-using-t-sql-for-xml-path)

Comment: please help me by letting me know how to read the XML from a file location and process this..

Answer (score 2):

you can use the Line of code like this

```
    SET @testXML.modify('delete  /INFO//*[not(@*)]')
```

This will remove all the nodes under `INFO` which do not have any attributes.

**Complete Code Example**

```
    DECLARE @testXML XML
    SET @testXML=            
                   ' <INFO>
      <Opp LocationID="1594743" ModifyDate="2015-04-01T23:50:01" MicrositeURLKey="O6UJ9A03XT6J" MDRPID="1594743" AccountID="A6UJ9A00OS1L" Account="Marquette University " RepName="Maggie Dolan" RequestDate="2015-04-01T23:48:07" OPPORTUNITYID="O6UJ9A03XT6J">
        <OppProduct Title="prepU for Jensen''s Nursing Health Assessment: A Best Practice Approach, Ecommerce, 3 Month Access (PREPU)" ISBN="9781469895727" Price="0.0000" OppProductID="Q6UJ9A15NMSF">
          <AccCourse>
            <contact />
          </AccCourse>
        </OppProduct>
        <OppProduct Title="Lippincott CoursePoint for Nursing Health Assessment: A Best Approach, Ecommerce Version, 12 Month Access (CoursePoint)" ISBN="9781496303134" Price="0.0000" OppProductID="Q6UJ9A15NMSG">
          <AccCourse>
            <contact />
          </AccCourse>
        </OppProduct>
      </Opp>
    </INFO>'
    select @testXML 
    SET @testXML.modify('delete  /INFO//*[not(@*)]')
    select @testXML
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Arun. The XML file is craeted dynamically, so could you please let me know how to pass the file name instead of content of file to above solution.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `XML modify()` to delete the nodes which do not have an attribute . Something like this.

```
DECLARE @xml xml =
'<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Opp LocationID="1594743" ModifyDate="2015-04-01T23:50:01" MicrositeURLKey="O6UJ9A03XT6J" MDRPID="1594743" AccountID="A6UJ9A00OS1L" Account="Marquette University " RepName="Maggie Dolan" RequestDate="2015-04-01T23:48:07" OPPORTUNITYID="O6UJ9A03XT6J"><OppProduct Title="prepU for Jensen''s Nursing Health Assessment: A Best Practice Approach, Ecommerce, 3 Month Access (PREPU)" ISBN="9781469895727" Price="0.0000" OppProductID="Q6UJ9A15NMSF"><AccCourse><contact/></AccCourse></OppProduct><OppProduct Title="Lippincott CoursePoint for Nursing Health Assessment: A Best Approach, Ecommerce Version, 12 Month Access (CoursePoint)" ISBN="9781496303134" Price="0.0000" OppProductID="Q6UJ9A15NMSG"><AccCourse ACCOUNTCOURSEID="2"><contact/></AccCourse></OppProduct></Opp>'

SELECT @xml

SET @xml.modify('delete //AccCourse[empty(@ACCOUNTCOURSEID)]')

SELECT @xml
```

For more information refer [delete (XML DML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms190254.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Building upon Arun Gairola answer:

> you can use the Line of code like this
>
> ```
> SET @testXML.modify('delete  /INFO//*[not(@*)]')
> ```
>
> This will remove all the nodes under INFO which do not have any attributes.

Since your XML is generated from a query, you can set the result into a variable and then delete the empty nodes from the variable.  Using your SQL above, you'd want to do something like this:

```
set @xml xml;
set @xml = (
    select <columns>
    from <tables>
    For XML AUTO, ROOT('INFO')
    )

set @xml.modify('delete  /INFO//*[not(@*)]')
select @xml
```

Using the complete sql you provided in your question, you'd want to do this:

```
set @xml xml;
set @xml = (select 
    Opp.OPPORTUNITYID as OPPORTUNITYID,
    Opp.CREATEDATE as RequestDate,
    (select USERNAME from sysdba.USERINFO where USERID=Opp.ACCOUNTMANAGERID) as RepName,
    (select Account from sysdba.ACCOUNT where ACCOUNTID=Opp.ACCOUNTID )as Account,
    (select ACCOUNTID from sysdba.ACCOUNT where ACCOUNTID=Opp.ACCOUNTID ) as AccountID,
    (select MDRPID from sysdba.ACCOUNT where ACCOUNTID=Opp.ACCOUNTID ) as MDRPID,
    (select Coalesce(acc1.accountid,acc.accountid) from sysdba.ACCOUNT  acc  left  join sysdba.ACCOUNT acc1 on acc.UNIVERSITYID = acc1.accountid where acc.ACCOUNTID=Opp.ACCOUNTID ) as UniversityID,
    (select Coalesce(acc1.account,acc.account) from sysdba.ACCOUNT  acc  left  join sysdba.ACCOUNT acc1 on acc.UNIVERSITYID = acc1.accountid where acc.ACCOUNTID=Opp.ACCOUNTID ) as University,
    (Opp.STARTDATE) as StartDate,
    (opp.enddate) as EndDate,
    Coalesce ( opp.PROMOCODE,'') as Promocode,
    Opp.MICROSITEURLKEY as MicrositeURLKey,
    opp.modifydate as ModifyDate,
    (select GUID from sysdba.ACCOUNT where ACCOUNTID=Opp.ACCOUNTID ) as LocationID,
    OppProduct.OPPPRODUCTID as OppProductID,
    OppProduct.PRICE as Price,
    OppProduct.CALCPRICE as CalculatedPrice,
    OppProduct.discount as Discount,
    (select pro.ISBN from sysdba.C_PRODUCT pro join sysdba.OPPORTUNITY_PRODUCT opppro on pro.C_PRODUCTID=opppro.PRODUCTID where opppro.OPPPRODUCTID=OppProduct.OPPPRODUCTID ) as ISBN,
    (select pro.TITLE from sysdba.C_PRODUCT pro join sysdba.OPPORTUNITY_PRODUCT opppro on pro.C_PRODUCTID=opppro.PRODUCTID where opppro.OPPPRODUCTID=OppProduct.OPPPRODUCTID ) as Title,
    AccCourse.ACCOUNTCOURSEID  AS ACCOUNTCOURSEID,
    AccCourse.COURSENAME as CourseName,
    AccCourse.MDRCLGCOURSE as CLGCourse,
    Contact.CONTACTID  as CONTACTID,
    Contact.FIRSTNAME as FirstName,
    Contact.LASTNAME as LastName,
    Contact.EMAIL as Email
from sysdba.OPPORTUNITY Opp
join sysdba.OPPORTUNITY_PRODUCT OppProduct on Opp.OPPORTUNITYID = OppProduct.OPPORTUNITYID
left join sysdba.C_PRODUCT Product on OppProduct.PRODUCTID = Product.C_PRODUCTID
left join sysdba.OPPPRODUCTCOURSE ProductCourse on OppProduct.OPPPRODUCTID = ProductCourse.OPPPRODUCTID
left join sysdba.OPPORTUNITYCOURSE OppCourse on ProductCourse.OPPORTUNITYCOURSEID = OppCourse.OPPORTUNITYCOURSEID
left join sysdba.ACCOUNTCOURSE AccCourse on OppCourse.ACCOUNTCOURSEID = AccCourse.ACCOUNTCOURSEID
left join sysdba.OPPCOURSECONTACT OppContact on OppCourse.OPPORTUNITYCOURSEID = OppContact.OPPORTUNITYCOURSEID
left join sysdba.CONTACT contact on contact.CONTACTID=OppContact.CONTACTID
For XML AUTO, ROOT('INFO'))

set @xml.modify('delete  /INFO//*[not(@*)]')
select @xml
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this one is better:

```
modify('delete  //*[not(node())]')
```

You can also refer to this:
[Delete Empty XML nodes](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4f8438d6-6b61-4254-8ed4-9e755cf5cd63/is-there-query-i-can-write-to-remove-empty-tags-from-a-xml-field?forum=sqlxml)