# Suppress Empty XML Node From SQL Query

Tags: sql, xml, tags

I have an SQL query that returns XML data. One of the nodes to be returned won't always have data and in the cases where there is no data, I get an empty self closing tag...

[< additionalDocument/>]

[image: 1]

If this section is empty, I don't want to see the tags at all, the output needs to just move on to the next section. From a quick search online and seeing similar questions, the consensus seems to be that it shouldn't matter and that the empty self closing tag won't create problems with syntax. However, the data is intended for import into a 3rd party system and their dev guys won't accept the file with this empty tag present. Is there any way of suppressing the section entirely when empty?
Thanks
Steve

Full query below...

```
                    @Consignment_id decimal(18,0),
                    @Supplier decimal(18,0)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE             @Orders table
                    (OSeqNum int identity,
                    OOrder_id decimal(18,0),
                    OProduct_id decimal(18,0),
                    OPurchaseOrder varchar(20),
                    OCases int,
                    OHealthCertRef varchar(20),
                    OHealthCertIssueDate date)
INSERT INTO         @Orders
                    (OProduct_id,
                    OPurchaseOrder,
                    OCases,
                    OHealthCertRef,
                    OHealthCertIssueDate)
(SELECT             Product_id,
                    PurchaseOrderNumber,
                    (SELECT SUM(Cartons) FROM Order_products WHERE order_id=Orders.Order_id AND Status='Active'),
                    HealthCertRef,
                    HealthCertIssueDate
FROM                Orders
WHERE               ConsignmentNumber_id=@Consignment_id AND Client=@Supplier)
SELECT      'OUT' AS direction,
            (CONVERT(varchar(8),Consignment_id)+(CONVERT(varchar(8),(SELECT TOP 1 OpurchaseOrder FROM @Orders)))+UPPER(CONVERT(varchar(3),(SELECT DepotLocation FROM General WHERE Uber=DeliveryPoint))))AS externalReference,
            ('New')AS messageType,
            storageLocationReference=
            CASE WHEN CollectionPoint='311208108054' THEN 'X-Dock'
            ELSE (SELECT DepotLocation FROM General WHERE Uber=CollectionPoint)
            END,
            ('1.0')AS version,
            (SELECT PointOfExit AS pointOfExit,
            PointOfEntry AS pointOfEntry,
            (SELECT     '1' AS category,
                        'D24' AS type,
                        (CONVERT(varchar(20),DestinationPortETADate,112)+SUBSTRING(DestinationPortETATime,1,2)+SUBSTRING(DestinationPortETATime,4,2))AS refNum
            FROM        Consignments
            WHERE       Consignment_id=@Consignment_id
            FOR XML PATH('additionalDocument'), TYPE)
            'additionalDocuments',
                    (SELECT     'ROVRN'AS code,
                                (TrailerNumber)AS text
                    FROM        Consignments
                    WHERE       Consignment_id=@Consignment_id
                    FOR XML PATH('additionalInformation'), TYPE)
                    'additionalInformations',
                    (SELECT     (SELECT Supplier# FROM General WHERE Uber=@Supplier)AS code
                    FOR XML PATH('declarant'), TYPE),
                    (SELECT     
                        (SELECT UPPER(CONVERT(varchar(3),(SELECT DepotLocation FROM General WHERE Uber=(SELECT DeliveryPoint FROM Consignments WHERE Consignment_id=@Consignment_id))))AS code
                        FOR XML PATH('consignee'), TYPE),
                        (SELECT
                            (SELECT BorderCountry AS country,
                            identification=
                                CASE WHEN Accompanied='true' THEN VehicleReg
                                ELSE FerryNumber
                                END,
                            '6' AS mode,
                            Accompanied AS isAccompanied
                            FOR XML PATH('borderTransportMeans'), TYPE),                        
                            (SELECT DepartureCountry AS country,
                            VehicleReg AS identification,
                            '30'AS identificationType,
                            '3' AS mode
                            FOR XML PATH('departureTransportMeans'), TYPE),
                            (SELECT 
                                (SELECT '1' AS sealQuantity,
                                    (SELECT
                                        (SELECT '1' AS seqNum,
                                                SealNumber AS identification
                                        FROM    Consignments
                                        WHERE   Consignment_id=@Consignment_id
                                        FOR XML PATH ('seal'),TYPE)
                                    FOR XML PATH ('seals'),TYPE)
                                FOR XML PATH ('transportEquipment'),TYPE)
                            FOR XML PATH('transportEquipments'),TYPE)
                        FOR XML PATH('consignment'),TYPE),
                        (SELECT (SELECT Supplier# FROM General WHERE Uber=@Supplier) AS code
                        FOR XML PATH ('exporter'),TYPE),
                        (SELECT (SELECT 'Aldi '+DepotLocation FROM General WHERE Uber=(SELECT DeliveryPoint FROM Consignments WHERE Consignment_id=@Consignment_id)) AS place
                        FOR XML PATH ('tradeTerms'),TYPE),
                        (SELECT (CONVERT(varchar(8),Consignment_id)+(CONVERT(varchar(8),(SELECT TOP 1 OpurchaseOrder FROM @Orders)))+UPPER(CONVERT(varchar(3),(SELECT DepotLocation FROM General WHERE Uber=DeliveryPoint))))AS traderReference
                        FOR XML PATH ('ucr'),TYPE),
                        (SELECT
                            (SELECT OSeqNum AS seqNum,
                            (SELECT
                                (SELECT     
                                            category=
                                CASE WHEN   (SELECT HealthCertificateRequired FROM Products WHERE Product_id=OProduct_id)='No' THEN NULL
                                ELSE        'C'
                                END,
                                            CONVERT(date,OHealthCertIssueDate,112) AS issueDate,
                                            lpcoExemptionCode=
                                CASE WHEN   (SELECT HealthCertificateRequired FROM Products WHERE Product_id=OProduct_id)='No' THEN NULL
                                ELSE        'AC'
                                END,
                                            OHealthCertRef AS refNum,
                                            type=
                                CASE WHEN   (SELECT HealthCertificateRequired FROM Products WHERE Product_id=OProduct_id)='No' THEN NULL
                                ELSE        '687'
                                END
                                FOR XML PATH('additionalDocument'),TYPE),
                                (SELECT     '1' AS category,
                                            'D94' AS type,
                                            FerryNumber AS refNum
                                FOR XML PATH('additionalDocument'),TYPE)
                            FOR XML PATH ('additionalDocuments'),TYPE),
                                (SELECT (SELECT CONVERT(varchar(50),Code)+CONVERT(varchar(50),(SELECT Supplier# FROM General WHERE Uber=@Supplier)) FROM Products WHERE Product_id=OProduct_id) AS itemId
                                FOR XML PATH ('commodity'),TYPE),
                                (SELECT OCases AS qty
                                FOR XML PATH ('goodsMeasure'),TYPE),
                                (SELECT
                                    (SELECT (SELECT CountryCode FROM Countries WHERE Country_id=(SELECT CountryOfOrigin FROM Products WHERE Product_id=OProduct_id)) AS country,
                                    type=
                                        CASE WHEN (SELECT COOPreferential FROM Products WHERE Product_id=OProduct_id)='Yes' THEN 'PreferentialOrigin'
                                        WHEN (SELECT COOPreferential FROM Products WHERE Product_id=OProduct_id)='No' THEN 'NonPreferentialOrigin'
                                        END
                                    FOR XML PATH ('origin'),TYPE)
                                FOR XML PATH('origins'),TYPE),
                                (SELECT
                                    (SELECT OCases AS quantity,
                                    @Consignment_id AS shippingMarks,
                                    'CS'AS type
                                    FOR XML PATH ('packaging'),TYPE)
                                FOR XML PATH('packagings'),TYPE)
                            FROM    @Orders
                            FOR XML PATH ('governmentAgencyGoodsItem'),TYPE)
                        FOR XML PATH ('governmentAgencyGoodsItems'),TYPE)
                    FOR XML PATH('goodsShipment'), TYPE)
            FROM
            Consignments
            WHERE Consignment_id=@Consignment_id
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
            'singleAdministrativeDocument'
FROM        Consignments
WHERE       Consignment_id=@Consignment_id
FOR XML PATH ('customsShipment'), ELEMENTS, TYPE
END
```

The section that I'm trying to suppress when empty is...

```
(SELECT     
                                            category=
                                CASE WHEN   (SELECT HealthCertificateRequired FROM Products WHERE Product_id=OProduct_id)='No' THEN NULL
                                ELSE        'C'
                                END,
                                            CONVERT(date,OHealthCertIssueDate,112) AS issueDate,
                                            lpcoExemptionCode=
                                CASE WHEN   (SELECT HealthCertificateRequired FROM Products WHERE Product_id=OProduct_id)='No' THEN NULL
                                ELSE        'AC'
                                END,
                                            OHealthCertRef AS refNum,
                                            type=
                                CASE WHEN   (SELECT HealthCertificateRequired FROM Products WHERE Product_id=OProduct_id)='No' THEN NULL
                                ELSE        '687'
                                END
                                FOR XML PATH('additionalDocument'),TYPE),
```

Is there any way of wrapping this in some kind of IF statement or equivilent?

Comment: What is your DBMS? Sample data and  the query  would also help

Comment: you may find some potential solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29598932/delete-empty-node-in-xml-file-using-sql

Without your DBMS, data, and query, it's tougher to give more specific advice.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a **minimal reproducible example**. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: Apologies for the delay, I've been away from the office. I have updated the original post to include the full query.

Comment: Assuming MS SQL Server, "for xml path" will, by default, omit empty nodes, I took a tiny example from your query as a test case: It does NOT include empty nodes in the output: https://dbfiddle.uk/J4d10NPH   I think you need to build a small test case for us that demonstrates the problem. NB: there is no data, no current result or expected result to work with currently.