# SQL BCP Export XML To UTF-8 Format

Tags: sql-server, xml, bcp

I have a query that executes a stored procedure and exports the results to an XML file via BCP. The process works, except that the encoding of the XML file is showing as UCS-2 and I am told that the system I will be importing it into needs it to be UTF-8. Various threads suggest this should be possible, but I can't seem to find the right syntax. My code below...

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[cli_sel_c4t_supplier_report]
                    @Consignment_id decimal(18,0),
                    @Supplier decimal(18,0),
                    @Username varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE             @fileName VARCHAR(50),
                    @sqlCmd VARCHAR(8000),
                    @sqlStr Varchar(8000)
SET                 @fileName = 'C:\C4T\' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @Consignment_id) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @Supplier) + '.xml';
SET                 @sqlStr='EXEC [Company Database].[dbo].[cli_sel_c4t_xml_data] @Consignment_id = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @Consignment_id) + ', @Supplier = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @Supplier) + ';';
SET                 @sqlCmd = 'bcp "' + @sqlStr + '" queryout ' + @fileName + ' -c -C65001 -T -S "SVRNAME\INSTANCE"';
EXEC                cli_ins_audit_c4t_file @Consignment_id=@Consignment_id, @Supplier_id=@Supplier, @Path=@fileName, @Username=@Username
EXEC                xp_cmdshell @sqlCmd;
END
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks

Steve

Comment: Did you try to check utility [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver15)? *-C { ACP | OEM | RAW | code_page } Specifies the code page of the data in the data file. Versions prior to version 13 (SQL Server 2016 (13.x)) do not support code page 65001 (UTF-8 encoding)*

Comment: Hi. I'm using SQL 2017 so I'm assuming UTF-8 is supported. My syntax is ' -c -C65001 -T -S "SVRNAME\INSTANCE"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate UTF-8 instead of UTF-16, use *-c* instead of *-w* parameter. The *-c* option in bcp export characters by single byte.

Explicitly specifying code page 1252, and UTF-8: `-c -C 1252`

Comment: Hi. I'm not using the -w parameter. I tried with - C1252 but this caused the code to fail

Comment: It should be a space after **-C**

Comment: Thanks Yitzhak, this appears to have done the trick

Comment: @steve_flynn, glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you.

Comment: @steve_flynn, if you can add some additional info to your older post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67822610/suppress-empty-xml-node-from-sql-query

Comment: I've updated the original post to include the full query. Thanks.